# WPF Bind many to one relationship returns empty results

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a Booking which has a list of TourGuides and I'm trying to create a Booking and list of TourGuides at the same time, the Booking binding is working, but the TourGuideOnTour is always coming back as null.

heres my models:

```
public class Booking : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public IList<TourGuide> TourGuidesOnTour {
        get {
            if (_tourGuidesOnTour == null)
                return new List<TourGuide>();
            return _tourGuidesOnTour;
        }
        set {
            _tourGuidesOnTour = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TourGuidesOnTour");
        }
    }
}

public class TourGuide : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    string _tourGuideFirstName;

    public string TourGuideFirstName {
        get { return _tourGuideFirstName; }
        set {
            _tourGuideFirstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TourGuideFirstName");
        }
    }
}
```

And here are my bindings:

```
    <Grid Name="myGrid" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <GroupBox Header="Tour Information">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Tour" Width="130"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="185">
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <Binding Path="TourName"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    <ExceptionValidationRule />
                                </Binding.ValidationRules>
                            </Binding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Header="Tour Guide Information">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TourGuidesOnTour, Mode=TwoWay}">

            </DataGrid>
        </GroupBox>
        <Button Name="Save" Content="Save" Click="Save_Click" Width="170" Height="40" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I set my Datacontext:

```
        public Booking ReturnValue;// = null;
    public CreateBooking() {
        InitializeComponent();
        ReturnValue = new Booking();
        myGrid.DataContext = ReturnValue;
    }
```

and `ReturnValue.TourGuidesOnTour` is equal to `null` :(

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Ran the code, just removed the button and added an item to the list, it all showed just fine. I always have problems with the autogeneratedColoumns so I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in your posted code where you are initialising the TourGuidesOnTour, i.e;

```
ReturnValue.TourGuidesOnTour = new List<TourGuide>();
```

If you don't, your getter will always return a new list of TourGuide, but never initialise the internal variable.

So, you could either Initialise the TourGuidesOnTour or perhaps if you modify your getter to the following;

```
get
{
  if (_tourGuidesOnTour == null)
     _tourGuidesOnTour= new List<TourGuide>();

   return _tourGuidesOnTour;
}
```

Comment: You're right, I set it in my constructor of booking instead. thanks you :)